# fill table from arraylists

Tags: java

I want to fill table `y` with data stocked in arraylist.
I have three arraylists: `bornesNom`, `bornesX`  and `bornesY`, and the table contains three columns `Nom`, `X` and `Y`.

I want to set the `TableModel` but don"t know how.

The table is based on this model :

```
TableModel  bornesTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(
new String[][] { { "One", "Two","Two" }, { "Three", "Four", "Four" } },
new String[] { "Nom", "X", "Y" });
```

Comment: You don't know how to apply the table model to the table? Since you have `TableModel` I assume you're working with Swing, right?

Comment: yes am working with the Swing, i don't know how to declare the String[][] and fill it with the data in array list.

Comment: the object String[][] will contains rows depending on how many rows found so it's flexible, so i don't know how to do that

Comment: it's somthing like String[][] arrays = { array1, array2, array3, array4, array5 };  but i don't know how many arrays it will contain, it depends on the data

Comment: Did you even look at my answer yet?

Comment: which answer ? sorry i didn't get it :s

Comment: Huh? You even posted a comment to it.

Comment: yes and i repplied, why u ask me if i looked at ur answer yet. Sorry my english is bad, i think i didn't get what u mean :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment I assume the actual problem is how to convert 3 lists into a 2-dimensional array.

Besides the fact that having 3 separate lists seems to be a serious flaw in your design (you'd better have one list of objects containing the data for one instance) I'll try and give you a hint:

Create a 2 dimensional array with the first dimension having the same size as the lists.
Then loop over all the lists simultaneously and extract the data at the given index. Create and fill a String array of length 3 and assign it to the index of the outer array.

I'll provide a small example but keep in mind that you'd have to handle cases when the listst don't match.

Bascially it might look like this:

```
List<String> listA = ...;
List<String> listB = ...;
List<String> listC = ...;

//note: the lists could have different lengths so this is unsafe
//I'll leave this as an excercise for you
int listLength = listA.size(); 

String array[][] = new String[listLength][];

for( int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++ )
{
  array[i] = new String[3];
  array[i][0] = listA.get( i );
  array[i][1] = listB.get( i );
  array[i][2] = listC.get( i );
}
```

Another option might be to roll your own `TableModel` based on the 3 lists but before you do that, try and replace the lists with a proper data structure.